# msproject - creating an indicator that more than one resource is allocated to the task

Tags: resources, ms-project, indicator

I'm fairly new to MSProject and i believe my request is pretty simple:

I would like that an indicator show an icon when a task has more than one resource allocated to it.

is it possible?
p.s my goal is that people wont be able to add more than one resources per task. if there is a way to enforce it the indicator is not necessary

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic formula is something like that: `InStr([Resource Initials],",")`. Please pay attention that "," is a list separator in my locale. For other people that could be ";" and so on. There is a property of Application object: `Application.ListSeparator` but it isn't available in plain formula definition - you can create your VBA function which will just return the value and use your function.

Variation of the formula depends on what field are you going to use for it. If you plan to use one of Flag fields - just add `> 0` at the end, for Number field you can just define a graphical indicator with `greater than 0` condition.

Another option is to write your handler for event `Application.ProjectBeforeAssignmentNew` and check if there are any assignments defined for the task already